# How can I convert time to a number format in oracle for a specific timezone

Tags: sql, oracle, date, datetime

My database shows the time in GMT.

I am able to convert the hour and minute part of it in number by doing:

`TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(CORE_UPDATE_TS, 'HH24MI'))`

where core_update_ts is the value received from database. However, my requirement is to convert the core_update_ts into America/Los_Angeles and then change it to Number.

I am not able to do this specific task. When I do,

```
to_number(to_char((from_tz(to_timestamp(to_char(CORE_UPDATE_TS, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'),
'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') ,'GMT') at time zone 'America/Los_Angeles'),'DD-MON-YYYY
HH24:MI'), 'HH24MI') i am getting error.
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the datatype of `CORE_UPDATE_TS` column?

If it is date, you should cast it to timestamp and simply specify the timezone, and then extract.

```
cast(CORE_UPDATE_TS as timestamp) at time zone 'America/Los_Angeles'

to_char(cast(CORE_UPDATE_TS as timestamp) at time zone 'America/Los_Angeles','HH24MI')
```

If it is timestamp, simply specify the timezone.

```
CORE_UPDATE_TS at time zone 'America/Los_Angeles'

to_char(CORE_UPDATE_TS at time zone 'America/Los_Angeles','HH24MI')
```

Comment: I did the same and got the error : CASE WHEN TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(CORE_UPDATE_TS at time zone 'America/Los_Angeles', 'HH24MI')) <= 130 THEN 'SUCCESS'", '                                            *', 'ERROR at line 14:', 'ORA-30084: invalid data type for datetime primary with time zone modifier',

Comment: What is the datatype of CORE_UPDATE_TS column? If it is date, cast it to timestamp first.

Comment: Are you sure it is timestamp? I can't reproduce the error. Run this query to check to check datatype. `select column_name, data_type from all_tab_columns where table_name = 'your_table_name_in_upper_case';`

Comment: Yes, you were right it was DATE format. The earlier solution works thank you so much